# Trying to use sed to replace in a tex end up with no such file or directory

Tags: bash, sed, directory

im new here and i haven't found a solution I am capable of understanding it for my problem.
I want to create a script that replaces Defined Variables with arguments given to the script.
I am using Windows 10 and the implemented bash beta version (dunno where i can look at it)
Also that script should convert the output tex into a pdf, and as of now i have no idea how to do this.
I start with the script with following:

bash mail.sh "Max Maria" Mustermann "Musterstraße 20" 1234 Musterstadt

My code from now:

```
touch ./test.tex
chmod 700 ./test.tex
more AB6.tex | awk -v pre="$1" '{gsub("VORNAME",pre)}1' | awk -v suff="$2" '{gsub("NACHNAME",suff)}1' | awk -v street="$3" '{gsub("STRASSE",street)}1' | awk -v plz="$4" '{gsub("PLZ",plz)}1' | awk -v city="$5" '{gsub("STADT",city)}1' >./test.tex
```

> Cany@DESKTOP-MSCQBI6:/mnt/c/Users/schin/Documents$ bash mail2.sh "Max
>   Maria" Mustermann "Musterstrasse 20" 1234 Musterstadt touch:
>   »./test.tex\r“ kann nicht berührt werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht
>   gefunden chmod: Zugriff auf »./test.tex\r“ nicht möglich: Datei oder
>   Verzeichnis nicht gefunden : Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

First is
touch: can't be touched: No such file or directory
chmod: Can't access ./test.tex\r (why the fuck \r???) No such file or Directory
Directory not found : No such file or directory

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edited it and nothing changed... still getting the "No such file or Directory" Error

Comment: can you post the exact error message with the context in your question?

Comment: For dynamic replacements you should really consider using awk: `awk -v replacement="$var" '{gsub("pattern", replacement)}1'`

Comment: Added the Error message

Comment: What is the "AB6.tex" file in the code?

Comment: Its just a standard latex letter in scrlt2 in KOMA

Comment: @andlrc Works fine but it wont let me output the standard output into a file

Comment: @andlrc I did that it tells me no such file or directory ._.

Comment: @TheECanyon It's because your input file doesn't exists.

Comment: @andlrc Shouldnt it be created by what I am doing now? Actually every line gives me an error and i have root access on everything...

Comment: @andlrc the wierd thing is... if i leave the redirection at the end it prints the correct thing i want into my console :/

Comment: @andlrc If i redirect to < ~/test.tex its an empty file

Comment: @andlrc So just if you want to know: The Linux Subsystem for Windows has a problem with handling operations in the windows file system. It doesnt find directorys correctly what gives us this error. Executing in the home directory works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message:

`Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

is because the current directory isn't in your path? So you should invoke the script via:

`./mail.sh "Max Maria" Mustermann "Musterstraße 20" 1234 Musterstadt`

In your scipt you just need to toggle-off and on the single-quotes belonging to the sed command so that the shell can expand your variables. So just use:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Mailscript
#
# Variablen
pre=$1
suff=$2
street=$3
plz=$4
city=$5
sed -e 's/VORNAME/'"$pre"'/g; s/NACHNAME/'"$suff"'/g;s/STRASSE/'"$street"'/g;s/STADT/'"$city"'/g;s/PLZ/'"$plz"'/g' file1 > file2
```

With file1

```
My VORNAME
Your NACHNAME
The STRASSE
STADT which is pretty
PLZ with primes
```

this yields file2

```
My Max Maria
Your Mustermann
The Musterstraße 20
Musterstadt which is pretty
1234 with primes
```

Comment: Did you invoke the command without writing 'bash ./mail.sh ...', but './mai.sh ...'? What does `which bash` tell you?

Comment: I did try ./mail.sh ill try with the brackets... what do you mean with which base?

Comment: `Cany@DESKTOP-MSCQBI6:/mnt/c/Users/schin/Documents$ which bash`

Comment: How can I see that? I am using the Ubuntu Subsystem Package for Windows Developers

Comment: What is printed in your console when you enter that?

Comment: /bin/bash as I started my script

Comment: So: `Cany@DESKTOP-MSCQBI6:/mnt/c/Users/schin/Documents$ which bash

Comment: Forget that comment,  I missclicked. If you enter:
`Cany@DESKTOP-MSCQBI6:/mnt/c/Users/schin/Documents$ which bash`
and you get `/bin/bash` and if you are doing the exact same steps as I said above (of course the script must be executable) it should work. Nevertheless I know nothing about the specifics of the Ubuntu Subsystem Package for Windows Developers

Comment: Well Thanks but i finally figured out how to work. The solution of andlrc was correct. The bash had a problem with printing into a file in a windows directory system. The wierd think is, i can cd to the directory but i cant change things with commands in it. I executed in home directory and everything is fine :)

Comment: So you maybe don't have write permission for that folder, respectively files in it